# efficient copy of data from boost::asio::streambuf to std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I need to copy the content of a (boost::asio::)streambuf to an std::string.

The following code works, but I think that there's an unnecessary copy between _msg and the temporary std::string:

```
Msg (boost::asio::streambuf & sb, size_t bytes_transferred) :
    _nBytesInMsg    (bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type buf = sb.data();

    _msg = std::string(
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf),
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf) + _nBytesInMsg);
}
```

I tried replacing with the following:

```
     _msg.reserve(_nBytesInMsg);
     std::copy(
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf),
        boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf) + _nBytesInMsg,
        _msg.begin()
    );
```

While this compiles, it doesn't copy anything to the _msg string.

Will the compiler (gcc4.4.7) optimize this case  - e.g. copy the streambuf straight to _msg without using a temporary?

Is there perhaps an iterator I can use with  boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type in order to make the std::copy work instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reserve` doesn't mean what you think it means. You can work out for sure what it means by [reading its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve). It is not the same as [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize); reserving space does not affect the container's [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

You need to actually insert elements into the string. Do this:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for copy
#include <iterator>     // for back_inserter

_msg.reserve(_nBytesInMsg);  // about to insert _nBytesInMsg elements

std::copy(
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf),
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf) + _nBytesInMsg,
    std::back_inserter(_msg)
);
```

Comment: I guess I meant resize; I always confuse those!  Thanks!

Comment: @stackuser: a) that's what documentation is for, and b) don't use resize; reserve and insert is better (the way I have it in the answer).

Comment: Is that an efficiency gain?

Comment: can you explain why reserve and insert is better?

Comment: @stackuser: Again, documentation... `resize` initializes all the elements, but you're immediately going to overwrite them. So that's pointless work.