# asio::streambuf to std::istream discarding new line

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I need to use the data read from an asio::socket (with ASIO_STANDALONE) as an istream

Up to now I have this code

```
asio::error_code ec;
auto bytes_transferred = asio::read_until(socket, buffer, '\n', ec);

if(!ec)
{
    buffer.commit(bytes_transferred);
    std::istream line(&buffer);
    // use line
    buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
}
```

the problem I'm facing is that the `'\n'` appears at the end of the istream, since it is not discarded by the `read_until`.

The declarations are

```
tcp::socket socket;
asio::streambuf buffer;
```

So I need to ignore the '\n' char when constructing the stream.
I tried (as I saw in this question [efficient copy of data from boost::asio::streambuf to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015803/efficient-copy-of-data-from-boostasiostreambuf-to-stdstring) ) with

```
if(!ec)
{
    // Ignore the last char ('\n')
    std::string line = std::string(asio::buffers_begin(buffer),
                                   asio::buffers_begin(buffer) + bytes_transferred - 1);
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    // use line
    buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
}
```

But this produces the following compile error

```
In instantiation of ‘struct asio::detail::buffers_iterator_types<asio::basic_streambuf<>, char>’:
lib/asio/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp:77:46:   required from ‘class asio::buffers_iterator<asio::basic_streambuf<>, char>’
file.h:58:78:   required from here
lib/asio/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp:60:5: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class asio::basic_streambuf<>’
     {
     ^
lib/asio/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class asio::buffers_iterator<asio::basic_streambuf<>, char>’:
file.h:58:78:   required from here
lib/asio/asio/buffers_iterator.hpp:455:43: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in ‘class asio::basic_streambuf<>’
   typename BufferSequence::const_iterator begin_;
```

and a few others always complaining about missing types.
I'm fairly new to C++ and this message is kind of cryptic to me, moreover I'm not sure this is the best approach, as I will have 3 copy of the same data (in the buffer, in the string and in the stream)

What could be a possible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of approaches here, but it's difficult to give good advice without knowing something about how you intend to use the `istream`.

One thing about this code is that you know with absolute certainty that there will be a newline at the end of the `istream`. There is no code path that can be taken that will not result in that (other than an I/O error, which you will catch early).

As a result it's straightforward to write code that expects the `\n` to be there and ignore it.

Obviously you want to avoid buffer copies if possible.

However, if you want to copy the entire streambuf into a string, you might try this:

```
auto buf = buffer.data(); /* where buffer is your asio::streambuf */
auto s = std::string(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf), 
                     boost::asio::buffer_size(buf) - 1); /* remove the newline */
```

Of course if you're looking to parse strings, numbers etc out of the istream then the fact that there is a newline on the end won't matter - it's just whitespace which is ignored by default.

This mini program demonstrates this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << 10 << std::quoted("Hello\" World") << '\n';
    auto payload = oss.str();

    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    std::ostream otmp(&sb);
    otmp.write(payload.data(), payload.size());

    // streambuf now contains string with newline

    std::string s;
    int i;
    std::istream itmp(&sb);
    itmp >> i >> std::quoted(s);

    std::cout << i << std::endl;   // expect 10
    std::cout << s << std::endl;   // expect Hello" World
}
```

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile with the samples relating to istream usage ignoring whitespace. Kudos for mentioning awesome newfangled `quoted` of course :)

Comment: The buffer is guaranteed to end with a new line. I'll be using the istream to parse it, but part of the validation is that the istream is empty at the end of the parsing (only ' ' and '\t' are accepted as trailing characters), so I need to remove the new line.

Comment: @sehe I have a feeling that the next question is going to be about efficient parsing with spirit... over to you :)

Answer (score 2):

The buffer iterators assume that you're not using a streambuf. If you can receive to a buffer (sequence) that would totally work.

However, you can perhaps just use

1. streambuf iterators:

   ```
   std::string line;
   // Ignore the last char ('\n')
   std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&buffer), bytes_transferred - 1, back_inserter(line));
   ```

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/838d8c2903fe3e9b)</kbd>**
2. iostream whitespace aware functionality (like `std::getline` and `std::skipws`, which is *enabled by default*).